# php Xpath return: non-object

Tags: php, xpath

With PHP XPath i searching custumers in xml file:

```
$this->xpath->query(/custumer/new[id="222"])->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

But if this customer don't exist in xml file, i get error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\www\test.php on line 17
```

how to avoid this error?

Comment: This is more like a question about null result handling good practice than XPath question.

Comment: I'm betting you could have avoided this error by spelling 'customer' correctly. Just a hunch.

Answer (score 5):

First check the **length** of the nodeList returned by XPATH->query. If it's not 0, there is an object.

```
$nodelist = $this->xpath->query('/custumer/new[@id="222"]');

if($nodelist->length)//a DOMNodelist has a length-property
{
  $result = $nodelist->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: +1 for being the first to get the `query(string)` syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this XPath expression**:

```
count(/custumer/new[id="222"])
```

and if the result is greater than `0`, then you will not get the described error in:

> ```
> $this->xpath->query(/custumer/new[id="222"])->item(0)->nodeValue
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but with count I always get error. $r = $this->xpath->query('count(/custumer/new[id="222"])')->item(0)->nodeValue;
if($r > 0)
 echo 'good';

Comment: @jonson: `count()` returns a number -- not a node-set. There must be a method in your programming language for the evaluation of XPath expressions that return just a number (not a node-set).